# WAR files are getting created in a new tomcat folder while building the project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, tomcat7, war

> I am using Apache Tomcat7.0.42 for my project and I have it under a
>   folder called sandbox. When I build my project in eclipse there is one
>   more new folder getting created under sandbox with name Apache
>   Tomcat7.0 and with a webapps folder inside it and all the war files
>   are getting saved here and not to my original webapps under
>   Tomcat7.0.42 and all the environmental variables are set to Tomcat7.0.42